# How to orientate a pgfplot 3D plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a spiral such that it is orientated as shown in the rough sketch. The spiral is coming out of the screen.

[image]

The script below yields the diagram shown at the end, but whatever I do I cannot seem to get the orientations as shown above. Looking at the pgfplot manual am I correct in thinking that I can only rotate about the z axis and vertically up and down? Any suggestions?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
axis lines=center,axis on top,
zmin=0, zmax=8,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,
ymin=-2,ymax=2,
width=6cm,height=6cm]
\addplot3+[no markers,line width=2pt,color=orange,domain=0:10*pi,samples=80,samples y=0]
  ({sin(deg(x))},
   {cos(deg(x))},
   {2*x/(5*pi)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change the parametrization so that you're using:

```
{2*x/(5*pi)},
{sin(deg(x))},
{cos(deg(x))}
```

which brings the spiral along the `x` axis.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
            axis lines=center,axis on top,
            zmin=-2, zmax=2,
            xmin=-2,xmax=8,
            ymin=-2,ymax=2,
        width=6cm,height=6cm]
        \addplot3+[no markers,line width=2pt,color=orange,domain=0:10*pi,samples=80,samples y=0]
        (
        {2*x/(5*pi)},
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {cos(deg(x))}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just for demonstration, here's the 'other' orientation (along the `y` axis)

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
            axis lines=center,axis on top,
            zmin=-2, zmax=2,
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
            ymin=-2,ymax=8,
        width=6cm,height=6cm]
        \addplot3+[no markers,line width=2pt,color=orange,domain=0:10*pi,samples=80,samples y=0]
        (
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {2*x/(5*pi)},
        {cos(deg(x))}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```