# How to draw a parametric 3D curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I would like to use tikz or a similar LaTeX package to draw the following curve in a three-dimensional coordinate system

(t^2, t*(1-t), 1-t) for t in (0,1).

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have a look at the `pgfplots` package to see if it will get you started :) A specific example can be found here, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161867/how-to-orientate-a-pgfplot-3d-plot

Answer (score 10):

*pgfplots* is an option:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1] (t^2,{ t*(1-t)}, 1-t);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

---

With `view={<azimuth>}{<elevation>}` you can rotate the view to an angle where the features of the curve are easier visible. If you want to help further with depth perception, you can for instance add e.g. support lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={60}{30},
    enlargelimits=false,
]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,0.1,...,1}
    { \draw[gray] (#1*#1,#1-#1*#1,1-#1) -- (#1*#1,#1-#1*#1,0);
    }

    \addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1] (t^2,t-t^2,1-t);

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You pictures looks almost exactly like I wanted them to be, thanks a lot! However, your code does not run for me. Copying exactly what you wrote, LaTeX gives me 'unknown anchor' for the command compat=1.12 and 'inaccessible' for the plot itself. Any ideas why?